# What happens after RestSharp RestClient.Execute and before OnActionExecuting?

Tags: c#, restsharp

My application (apparently) hangs 6-7 seconds after any `RestClient.Execute`, before reaching `OnActionExecuting`.
Is there any call i could try to intercept in the middle?